# Can't display CSV file in pyspark(ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined by the first 100 rows, please try again with sampling)

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm getting an error while displaying a CSV file through Pyspark. I've attached the PySpark code and CSV file that I used.

```sql
from pyspark.sql import *
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.xxocxxxxxxx","xxxxx")

time_on_site_tablepath= "wasbs://dwpocblob@dwadfpoc.blob.core.windows.net/time_on_site.csv"
time_on_site = spark.read.format("csv").options(header='true', inferSchema='true').load(time_on_site_tablepath)

display(time_on_site.head(50))
```

The error is shown below

```sql
ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined by the first 100 rows, please try again with sampling
```

CSV file format is attached below

```
time_on_site:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame

next_eventdate:timestamp
barcode:integer
eventdate:timestamp
sno:integer
eventaction:string
next_action:string
next_deviceid:integer
next_device:string
type_flag:string
site:string
location:string
flag_perimeter:integer
deviceid:integer
device:string
tran_text:string
flag:integer
timespent_sec:integer
gg:integer
```

CSV file data is attached below

```
next_eventdate,barcode,eventdate,sno,eventaction,next_action,next_deviceid,next_device,type_flag,site,location,flag_perimeter,deviceid,device,tran_text,flag,timespent_sec,gg
2018-03-16 05:23:34.000,1998296,2018-03-14 18:50:29.000,1,IN,OUT,2,AGATE-R02-AP-Vehicle_Exit,,NULL,NULL,1,1,AGATE-R01-AP-Vehicle_Entry,Access Granted,0,124385,0
2018-03-17 07:22:16.000,1998296,2018-03-16 18:41:09.000,3,IN,OUT,2,AGATE-R02-AP-Vehicle_Exit,,NULL,NULL,1,1,AGATE-R01-AP-Vehicle_Entry,Access Granted,0,45667,0
2018-03-19 07:23:55.000,1998296,2018-03-17 18:36:17.000,6,IN,OUT,2,AGATE-R02-AP-Vehicle_Exit,,NULL,NULL,1,1,AGATE-R01-AP-Vehicle_Entry,Access Granted,1,132458,1
2018-03-21 07:25:04.000,1998296,2018-03-19 18:23:26.000,8,IN,OUT,2,AGATE-R02-AP-Vehicle_Exit,,NULL,NULL,1,1,AGATE-R01-AP-Vehicle_Entry,Access Granted,0,133298,0
2018-03-24 07:33:38.000,1998296,2018-03-23 18:39:04.000,10,IN,OUT,2,AGATE-R02-AP-Vehicle_Exit,,NULL,NULL,1,1,AGATE-R01-AP-Vehicle_Entry,Access Granted,0,46474,0
```

What could be done to load the CSV file successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no issue in your syntax, it's working fine.
The issue is in your data of CSV file, where the column named as `type_flag` have only None(null) values, So it doesn't infer it's Datatype.

So, here are two options.

1. you can display the data without using head(). Like
   `display(time_on_site)`
2. If you want to use `head()` then you need to replace the null value, at here I replaced it with the empty string('').

   `time_on_site = time_on_site.fillna('')
    display(time_on_site.head(50))`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, probably a bug, even if you provide a schema on the `spark.read.schema(my_schema).csv('path')` call
you get the same error on a `display(df.head())` call
the `display(df)` works though, but it gave me a WTF moment.

Comment: have to edit your answer and make it easier for readability.